# Xero Invoice - API Character limit in Apex Salesforce

Tags: apex, api, httprequest, xero

I'm new to salesforce and i'm trying to Integrate Xero Invoice.

While calling the API **GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/** i've got one question in my mind that what will be the character limit of URL/API for making the HTTP request?
for example, i want to specific Invoices which matches ContactIds

```
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/?IDs=220ddca8-3144-4085-9a88-2d72c5133734,88192a99-cbc5-4a66-bf1a-2f9fea2d36d0
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer has a [limit of 2048](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/208427/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer) characters other browsers has higher limit.

**URL character limit for Internet Explorer**

"Microsoft Internet Explorer has a maximum uniform resource locator (URL) length of 2,083 characters. Internet Explorer also has a maximum path length of 2,048 characters. This limit applies to both POST request and GET request URLs. If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.

**URL character limit outside Internet Explorer**
If you consider browsers other than Internet Explorer, then the next limit you run into is the Content Delivery Network HEADER limit. If the URI size exceeds 4 K, the server generates a 4xx/5xx error, depending on the environment.

Source: [URL character limit for Get requests](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/scene7/kb/base/is_protocol-_-forming_is/url-character-limit-get-requests.html)

Comment: Thanks Sir, for the quick response.